# jQuery UI draggable event handling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to stop the revert event on a draggable element if that element has been dropped on a valid droppable object. How do I stop the revert from happening?

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery UI draggable and droppable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by "in the right place" you mean a `droppable` element. If that's the case, just use the `revert` option, set to `'invalid'`:

```
$("#drag").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wKBRk/

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted to achieve.I thought i had to somehow target the draggable element and stop that from reverting.Thanks!